# Как определить шрифт и размер текста?

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеются `RichTextBox` и 2 `ComboBox`, в одном из которых хранятся все загруженные шрифты, а в другом можно задавать размер текста.
Шрифты успешно загрузил. Успешно меняет шрифт текста на выбранный в `ComboBox` и успешно меняет размер текста.
`ComboBox`'ы работают фиксировано. То есть какой элемент выбран там, такой и остается. А нужно сделать так, чтобы при поставке курсора на текст программа узнавала, какой шрифт и какой размер стоят у выбранного текста, и меняла элементы в `ComboBox`'ах. То есть тот же самый алгоритм работы что и в *Word*'е.

Как это сделать?

Текущий код:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection fonts = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
    foreach (FontFamily font in fonts.Families)
    {
        FontBox.Items.Add(font.Name);
        FontBox.SelectedItem = "Times New Roman";
    }
}

private void FontBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float size = Convert.ToSingle(SizeBox.Text);
    ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(FontBox.Text, size);
    ContentBox.Select();
}

private void SizeBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float size = Convert.ToSingle(SizeBox.Text);
    ContentBox.SelectionFont = new Font(FontBox.Text, size);
    ContentBox.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете подписаться на событие `SelectionChanged` элемента `RichTextBox`, а в обработчике события из свойства `SelectionFont` брать имя шрифта и размер и задавать их свойству `SelectedItem` у элементов типа `ComboBox`.

```
//подписка на событие в конструкторе формы
ContentBox.SelectionChanged += ContentBox_SelectionChanged;

private void ContentBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var font = ContentBox.SelectionFont;
    ContentBox.SelectedItem = font.Name;
    SizeBox.Text = Convert.ToString(font.Size);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо.